# Fluent validation NotEqual is not trigger

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

I wish to validate that secondary password cannot same as first password by using Fluent Validation

```
RuleFor(x => x.FirstPassword).NotEqual(x => x.SecondPassword).WithMessage("Second password are not allow to same as first password.");
```

FirstPassword enter => 123456

SecondPassword enter => 123456

Both entered same password, but the validation not trigger

**Update**

Try another way by using `Must` but still not trigger

```
RuleFor(x => x.FirstPassword).Must((x, y) => y != x.SecondPassword).WithMessage("Second password are not allow to same as first password.");
```

Comment: where are you expecting the controls to be validated? some validations are not supported on client-side. https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html#clientside-validation

Answer (score 2):

You can try like below:

```
RuleFor(u => u)
.Must(u => u.FirstPassword != u.SecondPassword)
.WithMessage("Second password are not allow to same as first password.");
```

Test Result:

[image]

Comment: @FeelRightz Sorry, I misunderstood. If you want secondary password cannot same as first password, just change == to != .

Answer (score 0):

```
RuleFor(x => x.FirstPassword) .NotEmpty().WithMessage(localizer["{PropertyName} must not be empty."]) .MinimumLength(8);

RuleFor(x => x.SecondPassword) .NotEmpty().WithMessage(localizer["{PropertyName} must not be empty."]) .NotEqual(x => x.Password).WithMessage(localizer["{PropertyName} do not match."]);
```

Comment: You could also consider this way